# Change default parameter names on Zapier/Calendly integration

Tags: javascript, zapier, calendly

We use calendly to make appoitments with possible clients. Through zapier we create leads on third party app with the information filled in the calendar invite.

WEhen I check the trigger on Zapier I can see:

```
tracking:
utm_campaig: null
utm_source: null
utm_medium: null
utm_content: null
utm_term:null
```

This parameters work as intended ?utm_campaign=test returns

```
tracking:
utm_campaign: test
```

I want to know if there is any way to change the name of the campaings as our clients are tech savy enough to know whether we are using UTMs and since we want to use for referral links in the future id like to change it to a less obvious campaing name that we can also make consistant with our other tracking methods

Comment: So you want to send a link to a client that looks like this: `calendly.com/juan/30min?utm_campaign=something_cryptic`, but when pushing information to a CRM in the Zapier integration, you want to rename the UTM campaign parameter from `something_cryptic` to e.g. `barbershop-owners`? Can you share your current Zapier setup?

Comment: No sorry, id like to change "utm_campaign" to "something_cryptic"  eg calendly.com/juan/30min?something_cryptic=1

Comment: I see. Unfortunately you can't rename the `utm_campaign` parameter name to something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Calendly app will only recognize certain query parameters on the booking page such as `utm_campaign` and `utm_source` as tracking parameters, and will save their value on the Invitee object. Any other parameters will be ignored.